# canvas.toDataURL to img src

Tags: javascript, canvas

I recently downloaded an open source webcam to gif script and when the gif is created it saves as a dataurl. Is their a way I can change this? I would rather it save in a folder on the server and be something like `http://example.com/folder/image.gif`

Code:

```
    *global GIFEncoder,encode64*/
var encoder = new GIFEncoder(),
    video = document.querySelector('video'),
    canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    localMediaStream = null,
    snapshotPause = 0,
    recording = true,
    framesPause = 120,
    maxFrames = 28,
    totalFrames = 0,
    t;

encoder.setSize(320, 240);
encoder.setRepeat(0);
encoder.setDelay(framesPause);
encoder.setQuality(90);

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
            video: true
        }, function (stream) {
            $('#start-image, #start-fake').hide();
            $('#video, #start').show();
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            localMediaStream = stream;
        }, function (e) {
            console.log('Error:', e);
        }
    );
} else {
    console.log('not supported');
}

function snapshot() {
    if (localMediaStream) {
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240);
        encoder.addFrame(ctx);

        var image = $('<img />').attr('src', canvas.toDataURL('image/gif'));
        $('#thumbs').append(image);
        totalFrames++;
        if (totalFrames === maxFrames) {
            recordingEnd();
        }
    }
}

    function recordingEnd() {
    var binaryGif = encoder.stream().getData(),
        dataUrl = 'data:image/gif;base64,' + encode64(binaryGif),
        gif = $('<img />').attr('src', dataUrl);

    totalFrames = 0;
    recording = !recording;

    $('#start').html('Start');
    clearInterval(t);
    $('#indicator').hide();

    encoder.finish();

    $('#result-gif').html('').append(gif);
    overlayShow('preview');
    //b64 = encode64(binaryGif);
}

function overlayShow(panel) {
    $('.panel').hide();
    $('#' + panel).show();
    $('#overlay-bg').show();
    $('#overlay').show();
}

function overlayHide() {
    $('#overlay-bg').hide();
    $('#overlay').hide();
}

$('#start').click(function () {

    if (recording) {

        recording = !recording;

        $('#thumbs-holder-close').show();
        $('#thumbs-holder').animate({
            'margin-left': '320px'
        }, 300);
        $('#thumbs').html('');
        encoder.start();

        $('#indicator').show().animate({
            width: '100%'
        }, snapshotPause, function () {
            $('#indicator').css({
                'width': '0'
            });
        });

        t = setInterval(function () {

            snapshot();
            $('#indicator').animate({
                width: '100%'
            }, snapshotPause, function () {
                $('#indicator').css({
                    'width': '0'
                });
            });
        }, snapshotPause);

        $(this).html('Stop');

    } else {

        recordingEnd();
    }

});

    $('#thumbs-holder-close').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#thumbs-holder').animate({
        'margin-left': 0
    }, 300);
});

$('#overlay-close').click(function () {
    overlayHide();
});

$('.new').click(function () {
    overlayHide();
});

$('#showSettings').click(function () {
    overlayShow('settings');
});

$('input[type=range]').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id'),
        val = $(this).val();
    $(this).next().html(val);
    window[id] = parseInt(val);
    if (id === 'framesPause') {
        framesPause = val;
        encoder.setDelay(framesPause);
    }
});

$('#save').click(function () {

     $.ajax({
         url: 'images/save.php',
         method: 'POST',
         data: {
             image: b64
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {
             var a = $('<a />').attr('href', "images/" + data.name).html('permalink');
             $('#url').append(a);
         },
         error: function(err) {
             console.log(err);
         }
     });


 });
```

Comment: To save the webcam video to the server, no clientside script should be involved, or am I missing something?

Comment: It takes snapshots of your webcam and turns it into a giF. Once it is finished it saves it as a dataurl rather than on the server itself so theirs no src. When I make the gif its urls is just a bunch of jumbled letters and numbers rather than an actual link because the gif does not save on the server, but rather it saves on the users computer itself which is where the dataurl link is coming from. Not sure if links are allowed, but this is the example. http://buddystack.com/cam/

Comment: Oops, I see now - clientside webcam. I had expected a webcam video stream from the server.

Comment: I see you have tried posting the image data to your server with ajax. What part of it does not work?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>##Convert your dataUrl into Blobs</strike>

```
function dataURLtoBlob(dataURL) {
  // Decode the dataURL    
  var binary = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1]);
  // Create 8-bit unsigned array
  var array = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
      array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  // Return our Blob object
  return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/gif'});
}
/* var file= dataURLtoBlob(dataURL); */
```

Now, you can add the Blob as FormData and send to server

### Sending data as Blob instead of dataUrl.

As bergi pointed out, the encode.stream().getData() actually returns a binary string.

```
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < binaryGIF.length; i++) {
   array.push(binaryGIF.charCodeAt(i));
}
// Return our Blob object
var file = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/gif'});

// Create new form data
var fd = new FormData();
// Append our Canvas image file to the form data
fd.append("sample-image-name-for-name-attribute", file);
// And send it
$.ajax({
   url: "my-rest-endpoint",
   type: "POST",
   data: fd,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
}).done(function(respond){
  alert(respond);
});
```

Hope it helps. You should be able to use the file on the server as you handle a normal file upload.

Comment: Please not! If you suggest to send blobs, then omit the image-data-to-url conversion, instead of converting back.

Comment: Oops, sorry. my bad. I mistook the actual question and thought encoder.stream().getData() returned dataURL.

If it already returns the binary string, then I don't see any problem.

Comment: Still, "*send your data as blobs not gif-data-urls*" might be a valid answer so you could reduce it to that.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your time.. This is what i'm trying to change.. The open source script information says as follow. """Initial version also had option to save end result to server, but after a few of my friend made ~200Mb of images in less than an hour I had to disable it. I was looking for some external service where images could be stored but for now your images will be only on your computer."""" Now what I am trying to do is enable it again so it does save on the server and not the persons computer itself. I'm trying to get each time this is used the gif will show up in a folder on my server

Comment: @JamesMaltby, try sending the Blob (please, use the code I just posted and edited) to your server and on server, simply handle it like how you handle normal file uploads.